# How to group by multiple columns with joins using linq

Tags: linq

How to group by multiple columns coming from different tables and finally sum the amount column

```
      var result = _employeeDAL.GetList(db =>
                        from es in db.Set<EmployeeSchedule>()
                        join est in db.Set<EmployeeSalaryType>() on est.Employee_Id equals es.Employee_Id
                        join et in db.Set<EmployeeType>() on est.Employee_Salary_Id equals et.Employee_Salary_Id
                        where es.Status == "JOINED" && es.JoinedDate.Year == 2017
                        select new
                        {
                            EmployeeName = es.EmployeeName
                           ,Amount = est.Amount ///----------> SUM THIS
                           ,EmployeeType = et.EmployeeType
                        });
```

Here's WHat I have tried

```
      var result = _employeeDAL.GetList(db =>
                        from es in db.Set<EmployeeSchedule>()
                        join est in db.Set<EmployeeSalaryType>() on est.Employee_Id equals es.Employee_Id
                        join et in db.Set<EmployeeType>() on est.Employee_Salary_Id equals et.Employee_Salary_Id
                        group new { es, est, et } by new { es.EmployeeName, et.EmployeeType } into grp
                        where es.Status == "JOINED" && es.JoinedDate.Year == 2017
                        select new
                        {
                            EmployeeName = es.EmployeeName
                           ,Amount = grp.Sum(g=>g.est.Amount)
                           ,EmployeeType = et.EmployeeType
                        });
```

Comment: so, what is the issue?

Comment: Causing timeout so just check if there is any other optimized approach to pull big data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just need to take into account that after the `group ... by ... into grp` clause the only variable in scope is `grp`.

So move the `where` clause before the `group by` and use `grp.Key` inside the `select`:

```
var result = _employeeDAL.GetList(db =>
    from es in db.Set<EmployeeSchedule>()
    join est in db.Set<EmployeeSalaryType>() on est.Employee_Id equals es.Employee_Id
    join et in db.Set<EmployeeType>() on est.Employee_Salary_Id equals et.Employee_Salary_Id
    where es.Status == "JOINED" && es.JoinedDate.Year == 2017
    group new { es, est, et } by new { es.EmployeeName, et.EmployeeType } into grp
    select new
    {
        EmployeeName = grp.Key.EmployeeName,
        Amount = grp.Sum(g => g.est.Amount),
        EmployeeType = grp.Key.EmployeeType,
    });
```